# Offline MathML rendring support in android app

Tags: android, mathjax, mathml

I want to render MathML offline inside Android app. I am using leathrum's APK using MathJax. Below is the code for setting up mathjax offline config(http://cs.jsu.edu/~leathrum/mjapp-src/full/MainActivity.java) :

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                              +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                                +"showMathMenu: false, "
                                +"jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
                                +"extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " 
                                +"TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                                  +"'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                              //+"'SVG' : { blacker: 30, "
                              // +"styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } "
                              +"});</script>"
                              +"<script type='text/javascript' "
                              +"src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                              +"></script>"
                              +"<script type='text/javascript'>getLiteralMML = function() {"
                              +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                              // below, toMathML() rerurns literal MathML string
                              +"mml=math.root.toMathML(''); return mml;"
                              +"}; getEscapedMML = function() {"
                              +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                              // below, toMathMLquote() applies &-escaping to MathML string input
                              +"mml=math.root.toMathMLquote(getLiteralMML()); return mml;}"
                              +"</script>"
                              +"<span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>","text/html","utf-8","");
```

Local Mathjax is in assets.It renders Tex Input properly but I am unable to configure it to take MathML as input and show result offline.

Comment: You might want to provide more background. At the very least a link to whatever you're using.

Comment: I am referring to code at http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/index.php/2012/08/01/standalone-mathjax-app-for-android/  It takes Tex input and renders output.  I want to take Mathml as input and render output.

Comment: Peter means you need to provide the actual code you are using, not a link to code you have modified for your purposes (we know you have had to modify it since you are chaining the input format).  Without that, there is virtually nothing we can do to analyze your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To render mathml offline you need to add MathJax library to your asset folder and configure the library with web view

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",
    "<html><head>" +
    " <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" />" +
    "</head>" +
    "" +
    "<body style=\"font-size:18px\" >" +
    "<b>Put here your equation</b> </br> " +
    "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">" +
    "  MathJax.Hub.Config({\n" +
    "  CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true },EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile?10:50) },displayAlign: \"left\",\n" +
    "  \"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } ," +
    "\n" +
    "    preferredFont: \"STIX\"}," +
    "extensions: [\"tex2jax.js\"],messageStyle:\"none\"," +
    "jax: [\"input/TeX\", \"input/MathML\",\"output/HTML-CSS\"]," +
    "tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\\\(','\\\\)']]}" +
    "});" +
    "</script>" +
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script>" +
    "" +
    "</body>" +
    "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");

loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I just wasted 24 hours for this.

Comment: you can also load MathJax.js from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.9/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML